# Is there a way to import multiple contacts via VCF to iPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone, amazon-s3, vcf-vcard

I have a VCF file with multiple contacts in there. The issue i am facing is i am hosting this on AWS S3 as a standard `.vcf` file. On android when this link is clicked, both contacts are saved no problem.

On iPhone however, the vCard does not save all contacts, it only allows it to save the first one on top of the vCard. Is there any way to change this vCard to allow all contacts to be downloaded to iPhones X and higher?

This will be a link on a webpage where a user can download multiple contacts so iCloud and Email solutions are inefficient for my needs.

Any help is appreciated

```
VERSION:3.0
PRODID:-//Apple Inc.//macOS 11.1//EN
N:Test;Test;;;
FN:Test Test
TEL;type=WORK;type=VOICE;type=pref:+19999999999
END:VCARD
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:3.0
PRODID:-//Apple Inc.//macOS 11.1//EN
N:Test;Test;;;
FN:Gonzalo Perez
TEL;type=WORK;type=VOICE;type=pref:+19999999999
END:VCARD
```

Answer (score 0):

If you name the file something.vcard it may work. I definitely distribute address info this way.

Make sure to put a blank line or two between each entry.

Comment: Still didn't work for me. Any other workarounds?